# How do I export my mongodb collection into a table on my website?

Tags: php, html, mongodb, export

I want to create a very simple table that lists all the data in a mongodb database.

The database is hosted locally and updated every minute with information scraped by scrapy.

There are two pieces of data that will populate this table and apart from the "_id" element they are the datatypes in the database.

Because there will be new data added frequently but irregularly I was thinking the data should be pulled only when the website is loaded.

Currently the webpage is nothing more than an html file on my computer and I'm still in the process of learning how to host it. I'd like to be able to have the database accessible before making the website available as making this information available is its primary function.

Should I write a php script to pull the data?

Is there a program that already does this?

Do you know of any good tutorials that would be able to break the process down step-by-step?

Comment: if you want to use java then you can use "kundera", a JPA based libray, which supports many databases, its like once you have written code for interaction with one database and you decide to move on to another database supported by this library then you won't be required to change anything in the code(just change client name in persistence.xml) and it even allows you to simultaneously store data across many datastores. github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/… github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Blogs--and-Articles

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to export the data into a file (like a csv) you could try this:
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mongodb-exporting-data-into-files/

The csv may be more useful if you are planning to analyze the data offline.

Otherwise, you could write a script in PHP or Node.JS that connects to the database and finds all the records and displays them.

The Node function you would want is called find:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find